# Mapstruct: Unknown property "updateDate" in result type com.integrator.license.License. Did you mean "updatedDate"?

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I am getting following error in Mapstruct. As per various posts this error should not appear in latest versions.

Following are all configurations:

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project Snow: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Projects/Now/src/main/java/com/integrator/util/LicenseMapper.java:[20,25] Unknown property "updateDate" in result type com.integrator.license.License. Did you mean "updatedDate"?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Code:

```
@Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "updatedDate", target = "updateDate", dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"),
            @Mapping(source = "purchaseDate", target = "purchaseDate", dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    })
    License entityToDao(com.integrator.vo.license.License source);
```

POM:

```
<properties>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
</properties>
 .
 .
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.10</version>
                        </path>   
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Is this issue in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your target is  `target = "updateDate"`

it should be `target = "updatedDate"`

you've missed the d in "updated"